# A bag contains $10$ coins numbered $1,2,2^2,2^3,\dots,2^9$

Tags: probability

A bag contains $10$ coins numbered $1,2,2^2,2^3,\dots,2^9$. First, A picks a coin randomly from the bag, notes down the number and returns it into the bag. Then B does the same, followed by C. The probability that the sum of the numbers obtained by A and B is equal to the number obtained by C is

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see from the fact that the coins are numbered with consecutive powers of two that $A+B=C$ iff $A=B=k$ and $C=2k$ (the next number up) where $0\le k<9$, which makes $9$ events out of $10^3=1000$, for a probability of $\frac9{1000}$.

Here $A,B,C$ mean the numbers the corresponding parties draw out.

Comment: Yep got that, now I understand I was doing a silly mistake, I was taking the total events to be 9^3, so , I was getting the wrong answer as 1/81, thnx Taxel

Comment: @AvikShakhari You can now accept my answer since you found it useful. Click the tick beside this answer; it should turn green.